# Beginner has trouble with comparing lists in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm new to stackoverflow and also new to programming.

I have to compare two lists in python3 and struggle to produce working code for half a day now.

```
a = [3,1,0,1,2,2]
b = [2,3,0,2,1,1]
```

The lists are always the same length and contain the same elements.

I have to order list `b` in accordance with list `a` (basically copy it), however I need to remember the swapping order.

For example as a first step I swap element `0` and `1` in list `b` to make it `[3,2,0,2,1,1]`.

Seconde step: Swap element `1` and `4`.

Third step: Swap elements `3` and `5`.

So in the end list `b` is identical with list `a` and I have created a third list with the swapping tupels `((0,1),(1,4),(3,5))`.

Thank you very much for helping me out.

My buggy code sample:

```
targetcounterlist: [3,1,0,1,2,2]
candidatecounterlist: [2,3,0,2,1,1]
for i in candidatecounterlist:
global uncommon_elements
        uncommon_elements = [(e, v) for e, v in enumerate(targetcounterlist) if candidatecounterlist[e] != v]
        
        print(candidatecounterlist)


        swap_tupel = uncommon_elements[0]
        swap_position = swap_tupel[0]
        swap_value = swap_tupel[1]
        
        if candidatecounterlist[i] == swap_value:
          

            candidatecounterlist[i], candidatecounterlist[swap_position] = candidatecounterlist[
                                                                               swap_position], \
                                                                           candidatecounterlist[i]
            uncommon_elements = uncommon_elements[1:]
        else:
            print("no match")
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method (look at `start` parameter):

```
a = [3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2]
b = [2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1]

out, i = [], 0
while a != b:
    if a[i] != b[i]:
        idx = b.index(a[i], i)
        b[i], b[idx] = b[idx], b[i]
        out.append((i, idx))
    i += 1

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 4), (3, 5)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and providing me with an answer. It is elegant and it works! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to loop over the elements of list_a. Then check at what position it is in list_b, and if it is not in the correct position swap it. This should work assuming that a solution is possible.

However, you should be careful about repeated values, to avoid that fixing, for example, the 5th element doesn't break a previous element that has already been fixed).

For your example the algorithm should do something like that:

1. The 0th element of A is 3, but a 3 is in the first position in B, swap 0 and 1: [3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1]
2. The 1st element of A is 1, but 1 is in the 4th position in B, swap 1 and 4: [3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1]
3. The 2nd element of A is 0, which is also in the 2nd position in B, next.
4. The 3rd element of A is 1, but 1 is in the 5th position in B, swap 3 and 5: [3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2]
5. etc...

Here, for example in step 4 is where you should be careful not to use the 1 in the 1st position since this would cause problems.

Now of course this isn't probably the most efficient algorithm, but it works. I let you try to write the actual code to implement it, or another one you came up with.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and generall helpfulness.